# Google Spreadsheets retrieving JSON feed

Tags: json, google-sheets, google-docs

I recently started using the "New Google Sheets" (spreadsheets) and they changed the URL to a shared public spreadsheet and I am unsure how to obtain a JSON feed of the spreadsheet data.

Based on data from this URL: https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample

I can obtain the JSON data from an older version spreadsheet using the key parameter found in a URL of this format: http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/feed/key/worksheet/public/basic?alt=json-in-script&callback=myFunc

However, the new sheets have a URL like this:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SOME-IDENTIFIER/pubhtml

Using "SOME-IDENTIFIER" in place of the key does not work, I'm not sure how I can pull the JSON feed from a new spreadsheet...  Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: [See here for detailed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26774243/1922144)

Answer (score 4):

The format you should use is this :

> ```
> https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/
> SHEET-IDENTIFIER/
> SHEET_INDEX/
> public/basic?alt=json-in-script&callback=JSON_CALLBACK
> ```

You can find SHEET_INDEX by looking at the end of the URL while editing the sheet.

> ```
> ...SHEET-IDENTIFIER/edit#gid=SHEET_INDEX
> ```

Make sure the spreadsheet is published (not only shared).
File/Pulish to the web...

Comment: Is there documentation somewhere which explains the arguments?

Answer (score 3):

I tried Vlad's answer and it didn't work; the editing url had gid=0, but in order to get the feed I wanted I had to put in 1 as the sheet index.