# Google new spreadsheets return JSON

Tags: json, spreadsheet

I am using this link to return JSON data, but it is not working now. It shows a "Invalid query parameter value for grid_id" error. Any ideas? Thanks.

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1fe--KCLag0QNEuYqSeBU2HPZLUoyvicxYfoONnglx-k/821619139/public/values?alt=json

reference link
[Google Spreadsheets retrieving JSON feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058574/google-spreadsheets-retrieving-json-feed/24569697#24569697)

Comment: I found a solution
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1fe--KCLag0QNEuYqSeBU2HPZLUoyvicxYfoONnglx-k/1/public/values?alt=json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something recently changed in how google assigns the codes for each worksheet.  For me, the key was to change the first worksheet from "0" to "od6".

The way to look them up is to use https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/YOUR-SPREADSHEET_ID_HERE/public/basic.  If I do that with your spreadsheet (https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1fe--KCLag0QNEuYqSeBU2HPZLUoyvicxYfoONnglx-k/public/basic), I see that the only worksheet id listed is "odl6521" - "821619139" no longer exists.  But if I go to https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1fe--KCLag0QNEuYqSeBU2HPZLUoyvicxYfoONnglx-k/odl6521/public/values?alt=json , I get out a json file that looks to be what you want.

Hope that helps!

Comment: eteq this worked for me except I had to change your GID parameter of `odl6521` to `1` with a clue I found from this post: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531351/retrieve-google-spreadsheet-worksheet-json

Comment: Actually the GID parameter can be replaced with an individual Worksheet ID within the collection.